# IntelliJ IDEA does not find operators of Observable in rxjs5

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, rxjs5

I just installed rxjs 5 beta 3 via `npm i rxjs@5.0.0-beta.3`.

I have the following example code:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs"

new Observable(o => o.next(42)).filter(() => true);
```

This code compiles perfectly well when using ts-node for example.

But when looking at this code inside IntelliJ IDEA, the `filter()` operator is not found.

When using operators on an Observable instance, they are not found either.

The suggested static members of `Observable` are:

- `create()`
- `if()`
- `throw()`

The suggested members of an instance of `Observable` are:

- `_isScalar()`
- `forEach()`
- `lift()`
- `subscribe()`

I also tried to import only what I need, but still my IDE tells me that `filter()` does not exist on the Observable instance:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter"

new Observable(o => o.next(42)).filter(() => true);
```

Any suggestions how to make IntelliJ IDEA know about the operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check [IDEA 2016.1.2 or higher](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.1+EAP)

*Note*: Directory `node_modules` must be not excluded from the project.

Otherwise, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38499577/1057218

*Note 2*: File `package.json` must contain the direct dependency (or devdependency) '`rxjs`'

Comment: I just downloaded the new IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 145.596.7 version and the problem still exists.

Comment: @user558398 so please follow the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20992

Comment: Same here, even thought this answer is marked as accepted it doesn't solve the problem. I still get validation errors on `.filter`/`.map` when importing with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: Downloading 2016.2 and "unexcluding" node_modules worked like a charm for me. Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 9):

To fix this issue you need to add RxJS as a javascript library in IntelliJ:

1. Go to **Settings** -> **Languages and frameworks** -> **JavaScript** -> **Libraries**
2. Click **Add...**
3. Add `node_modules/rxjs` by clicking the **+** button
4. Click all the **OK** buttons until you are back in your editor.

This solution is tested to work on IDEA 2016.1.3

Comment: sorry but that does not work in IDEA Ultimate 2016.2
http://pasteboard.co/3KvUZkSDv.png, after hitting apply the error persists. Also I do not believe it is good to add rxjs to the libraries as node_modules is the "library root" already.

Comment: this worked for me, but why do I need to add rxjs manually when node_module is already added?

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer doesn't work. I have tested [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.2+EAP) (`ideaIU-162.1447.7`) and the problem still persist.

The rabbit hole goes as follows:

1. In the accepted answer you find a link to version [2016.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.1+EAP), but that doesn't fix the problem.
2. Then you see a comment with a [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.1+EAP) to the IntelliJ bugtracker, where OP has the first/top comment.
3. At the bottom of that issue/bug thread you find a comment [saying](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20992#comment=27-1447408) IDEA 2016.2 162.426.1 EAP will definitely fix the problem, it doesn't.

Bottom line, if you import all of what RxJS has to offer with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` IntelliJ will still complain that it can't find methods like `.map` and `.filter`

Comment: could you please try IDEA 2016.2 release version?

Comment: As I stated at the very first line I tried this in version **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 EAP**

Comment: yes, 2016.2.1 EAP is an eap version. I mean stable 2016.2 version

Comment: + check that node_modules aren't excluded from your project